# Conditionally joining - COALESCE vs OR - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I am working with a dataset that looks like the following (did not create fiddle since it is so small)

I have a table `tblReqs`, with a basic structure like this:

```
| Onum | Pnum | ReqNum |
|:----:|:----:|:------:|
| NULL | P427 | RN1148 |
| NULL | P324 | RN1725 |
| NULL | P229 | RN1242 |
| O396 | NULL | RN1457 |
| O380 | NULL | RN1205 |
| O258 | NULL | RN1482 |
```

I then have a table of straight numbers, called `tblnums`, like this:

```
| nums |
|------|
| O258 |
| O370 |
| O490 |
| O314 |
| O379 |
| P341 |
| P230 |
| P280 |
| P324 |
| P395 |
```

I need to *conditionally join* `tblnums` to `tblReqs`. Either the `Onum` or the `Pnum` in `tblReqs` would be equal to the `nums` field in `tblnums`.

The goal would be a dataset that looks like this:

```
| nums | ReqNum |
|:----:|:------:|
| O258 | RN1482 |
| O370 |        |
| O490 |        |
| O314 |        |
| O379 |        |
| P341 |        |
| P230 |        |
| P280 |        |
| P324 | RN1725 |
| P395 |        |
```

I know I can use the `OR` operator in a join like so:

```
   SELECT
    tblnums.nums,
    tblReqs.ReqNum

FROM
    tblnums
        LEFT JOIN tblReqs ON tblnums.nums = tblReqs.Onum OR tblnums.nums = tblReqs.Pnum
```

But I have recently learned about `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    tblnums.nums,
    tblReqs.ReqNum

FROM
    tblnums
        LEFT JOIN tblReqs ON tblnums.nums = COALESCE(tblReqs.Onum, tblReqs.Pnum)
```

Is there a preference to one over the other? I understand I could try both on my dataset, but measuring time is not a good metric as it is subject to so many other constraints (DB maintenance, network bandwidth, cpu / ram power, etc). Additionally, I cannot pull many metrics through SQL Developer since my IT team has it locked down.

Which of the two methods is preferred for conditional joins, `OR` or `COALESCE`? What is happening from a run-time complexity perspective, etc?

Comment: You could look at the execution plans as a starting point. But note that they are only equivalent if your first tables doesn't allow both Onum and Pnum to be non-null in the same row. `OR` would match both in that case; `COALESCE` would only match Onum, That doesn't affect your sample data of course, but your real data might have values in both columns.

Comment: I know for sure that both columns cannot be filled in; it can only be one of the two, which is why I was not sure if there was a performance difference between `OR` or `COALESCE`, without using time-to-run as a reliable metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an upside to using coalesce (or NVL for that matter) in that you can take advantage of [function-based indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS005), to improve query performance.

Setup:

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 09:21:33> create table tblreqs (onum, pnum, reqnum primary key) as
  2  with t (onum, pnum, reqnum) as (
  3  select NULL, 'P427', 'RN1148' from dual union all
  4  select NULL, 'P324', 'RN1725' from dual union all
  5  select NULL, 'P229', 'RN1242' from dual union all
  6  select 'O396', NULL, 'RN1457' from dual union all
  7  select 'O380', NULL, 'RN1205' from dual union all
  8  select 'O258', NULL, 'RN1482' from dual
  9  ) select * from t;

Table created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 09:21:33> create table tblnums (nums primary key) as
  2  with t (nums)as (
  3  select 'O258' from dual union all
  4  select 'O370' from dual union all
  5  select 'O490' from dual union all
  6  select 'O314' from dual union all
  7  select 'O379' from dual union all
  8  select 'P341' from dual union all
  9  select 'P230' from dual union all
 10  select 'P280' from dual union all
 11  select 'P324' from dual union all
 12  select 'P395' from dual
 13  ) select * from t;

Table created.
```

Please note how in the option below oracle cannot take advantage of indexes because of the conditional join (TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL on TBLREQS):

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 09:21:33> explain plan for
  2  SELECT n.nums,
  3         r.ReqNum
  4    FROM tblnums n
  5    LEFT JOIN tblReqs r ON n.nums = r.Onum OR n.nums = r.pnum;

Explained.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 09:21:33> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1571794044

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                 |    10 |   130 |    31   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER         |                 |    10 |   130 |    31   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN           | SYS_C0047401    |    10 |    50 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   VIEW                      | VW_LAT_EB747914 |     1 |     8 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| TBLREQS         |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter("R"."ONUM" IS NOT NULL AND "N"."NUMS"="R"."ONUM" OR "R"."PNUM" IS NOT
              NULL AND "N"."NUMS"="R"."PNUM")

17 rows selected.
```

Now if we create a function-based index using the coalesce function oracle detects that the index exists and will use it to improve the join performance, without need for a full table scan (INDEX RANGE SCAN on the newly created IDX_COALESCE_ONUM_PNUM):

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 09:21:33> create index idx_coalesce_onum_pnum on tblreqs (coalesce(Onum, Pnum));

Index created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 09:21:33> explain plan for
  2  SELECT n.nums,
  3         r.ReqNum
  4    FROM tblnums n
  5    LEFT JOIN tblReqs r ON n.nums = COALESCE(r.Onum, r.Pnum);

Explained.

FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 09:21:33> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 605824869

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                        |    10 |   160 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |                        |    10 |   160 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN                    | SYS_C0047401           |    10 |    50 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TBLREQS                |     1 |    11 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX_COALESCE_ONUM_PNUM |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("N"."NUMS"="R"."SYS_NC00004$"(+))

16 rows selected.
```

Comment: this is a great idea, and something I didn't even consider (nor knew how to do). The `Cost` metric defined in your table, would that be dependent on the CPU running the query? (I ask because I am trying to justify one vs the other)

Comment: Cost does take into account factors like IO, CPU and network trips, plus db object statistics. Please note that comparing costs between 2 distinct SQL statements is not reliable. The cost is an estimate Oracle makes and is meaningful only in the context of comparing SQL execution plans to try and find which path to access the data will be faster and consume less resources among all the plans available for one specific SQL statement. Typically the optimizer does a good job in it, and sometimes it does not, by making wrong assumptions based on poor statistics about table data.

Comment: This is some documentation on DBMS_XPLAN: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xplan.htm By default Oracle uses a table called PLAN_TABLE to store explain plan estimates. I just used DBMS_XPLAN above because it's the quickest way to look under the hood at what Oracle is doing when running a SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In general, functions and `or` can impede optimization. Both should have very similar performance.

I think the best method might be two joins:

```
SELECT n.nums,
       COALESCE(ro.ReqNum, rp.ReqNum) as reqNum
FROM tblnums n LEFT JOIN
     tblReqs ro
     ON n.nums = ro.Onum LEFT JOIN
     tblReqs rp
     ON n.nums = rp.Pnum AND
                 ro.Onum IS NULL;  -- no match the first time
```